# Counting the unique values in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree. So far, I've been able to sort the tree using in-order traversal. My tree is a tree of strings being read from a file, and I want to count all the unique values within the tree (I need to use the duplicates for another part of the code, so I can't make a new tree with no duplicates and count that). I need to traverse the tree to count these unique values.

I thought it would be easy to count the unique values if everything is sorted, I'm not sure why I am having problems.

This code works:

```
int uniqueCount(node* root, string c){
  int count = 0;
  if(root == NULL)
    return 0;

  else

  if (root->word == c)
  count++;

  return 1 + uniqueCount(root->left, c) + uniqueCount(root->right, c);
}
```

But it counts all the nodes, including the duplicates, which I don't want.

So, I wrote this:

```
int uniqueCount(node* root, string c){
  int counter = 0;
  string found, temp = " ";

  if (root == NULL){
    counter = 0;
  }
    else{
    if (c == root->word){
      temp = c;
    }
      if(found != temp){
        counter++;
        found = temp;
      }
  }

return 1 + uniqueCount(root->left, c) + uniqueCount(root->right, c);
}
```

But now my code prints nothing.

Here's my main code:

```
int main()
{
  node *T;
  ifstream fin;
  string c;
  int counter;

  fin.open("C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\mytest.txt");
  if(fin.fail())
  {
    cout << "Could not find your file. Shutting down.";
    exit(1);
  }

  else{
  T = NULL;

  while(!fin.eof()){
    if (c != " ")
    bInsert (c, &T);
    counter = uniqueCount(T, c);
    fin >> c;
  }
}


cout << "Number of distint words are: " << counter << endl;
  cout << "In-order\n";
  inOrder(T); cout << endl;
```

I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: So far this semester, the data structures we've learned are stacks, queues, lists, and now, binary trees. So for this project, I would only be allowed to use these data structures. I would not be allowed to use hash tables, or maps, or sets, etc.

Comment: Do any traversal and just add the node string to a `std::unordered_set<string>`.  An `unordered_set` automatically does not store duplicates.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hello, thanks for your comment! I have not learned sets or unordered sets in this course, so we wouldn't be allowed to use it.

Comment: Then please state what you can use.  Also, why can't you simply just "read ahead" and use this thing you discovered called "unordered_set"?  I really don't get the reasoning of "I didn't get to chapter X in my book, so I can't use it".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've edited my question accordingly. Also, it's the professor that sets these rules, so I just have to follow them.

Comment: It looks like uniqueCount will recursively search and count over the whole tree, but you are calling it inside of the same while loop that you construct the tree. If you move it to being called after the whole tree is constructed what is the behavior?

Comment: @Kieran Same problem - nothing outputs. I have noticed that when I comment out 'counter = uniqueCount(T,c)' , the code prints out again, so I think the problem must come from there, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean prints nothing as in the program appears to be non responsive? In the second version of the function you appear to have removed the 'return 0' line without this I do not see how you break the recursion to get back to main

Comment: @Kieran When I comment out counter = uniqueCount(T,c), it prints out this: http://prntscr.com/sadiru , however when I add that line, no matter where I put it, it prints out this: http://prntscr.com/sadjlv. Also, I don't understand why adding return 0 would work if I'm already returning  1 + uniqueCount(....). Wouldn't it stop recursing once both the left and the right reached the end of their leaves?

Comment: Have you tied running it under a debugger to step through what it is doing? Or see if it is encountering any errors?

Comment: *So far this semester, the data structures we've learned are stacks, queues, lists* -- What is stopping you from utilizing these data structures in getting the unique count?  You could easily traverse the tree using breadth-first-search, which utilizes a queue.  For each node, put that in a list if it doesn't already occur.  That can be done using a binary search.  Also, what was the policy you used when you built the tree with duplicates, i.e. which branch did the duplicate item use, the left or the right branch?

Comment: @Chichi - Check my answer again I debugged it. It should be node->right!=NULL not node->left!=NULL. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: @BRUCE Its no worries. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count unique content of binary tree then try this code this format

```
void uniquecount(struct Node* node) 
{ 
    int count=0;//make this global to bring value out of function
    if (node == NULL) 
        return; 
    uniquecount(node->left); 
    if(node->right!=NULL && node->right==node->data)
    count--;
    else
    count++;
    uniquecount(node->right); 
}
```

Just make sure that while creating binary tree insert the node to right if parent data is equal.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is to count the unique occurrences in your text, try this:

```
int main()
{
  string c;
  ifstream fin;
  set<string> unique_words;

  fin.open("C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\mytest.txt");
  if(fin.fail())
  {
    cout << "Could not find your file. Shutting down.";
    exit(1);
  }

  else{

  while(!fin.eof()){
    fin>>c;
    unique_words.insert(c);
  }
  int counter=unique_words.size();
  cout << "Number of distint words are: " << counter << endl;
  cout << "In-order\n";
  for(auto a:unique_words)
    cout<<a<<' '; //Use whatever separator you want
  return 0;
}
```

The idea here is that the `set` container implements a binary tree. But no duplicate are allowed. As the set contains only unique values, then the number of unique elements is nothing less than the size of the set. If you really want to keep the duplicate then use `multiset`.

Comment: I apologize for not making it clearer - I have to traverse the tree. I also can't use sets.

Comment: My bad, I misread that in the P.S! How about creating a vector in which you push back only the new elements. You verify if the word is in that vector, if it is not there you append it, if it is there you continue the loop. It is quite slow but should work I guess.